# How can I force an angular validation directive to run?

Tags: validation, angularjs

I've created a validation directive for my form.
It basically validates a fields value based on data from another field.

It works perfect :-)

My problem is that if the other field changes after the validation was executed, the validation will not run again.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('validateInteger', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          var int1val = scope.int1;
          scope.int2valid = (viewValue > int1val) ? "valid" : undefined;
          if (scope.int2valid == "valid") {
              ctrl.$setValidity('higher', true);
              return viewValue;
          } else {
              ctrl.$setValidity('higher', false);
              return undefined;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/vCFFQ/

Comment: This won't correct a "validation" issue, but you can hide the div with `ng-hide="int2>int1"`, setting the `>` operator right in the hide expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a really bad idea to refer explicitly to some fields in your directive. As you can see, this has a lot of drawbacks : unportability, code repetition, brittleness, …

Just make something like that :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="int2" validate-greater-integer="int1" />
```

And :

```
myApp.directive('validateGreaterInteger', function() {
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        otherInteger : '=validateGreaterInteger',
    }
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        if (viewValue > scope.otherInteger) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('higher', true);
            return viewValue;
        } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('higher', false);
            return undefined;
        }
    }
});
```

You can then simply do [the typical state control](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) (see the section "Binding to form and control state" for an exemple).

Please notice that, in this case, you can also more simply use [input[number]](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.number) and its `min` parameter.

---

**Edit after the discussion in comments :**

Well, the functions in `NgModelController.$parsers` are obviously called only when the content of the model changes. What you want to do is to make validation whenever `int1` or `int2` change. So just do it :-) :

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch('data', function (data) {
      if (data.int2 > data.int1) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('higher', true);
          return data.int2;
      } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('higher', false);
          return undefined;
    }
  }, true);
```

Use your own validation variable (`int2valid` in your Fiddle) is also very strange. Please use [the typical state control](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), with something like `form.int2.$error.higher`.

Comment: I do know the drawbacks - this was only a simple example of my validation directive :-) The validation checks the integer for several things (min, max, some calculation based on other fields etc.) And when the other fields are changed by the user, I need the validation to run again.
I've tried to use a scope function instead (called by ng-change on the other fields), but I can't manage to use the $setValidity function from the scope - I get:
`Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method '$setValidity'`

Comment: Does my proposal not solve the problem ? In brief : just use as many parameters as necessary in your directives, bind them to the local ```scope``` and make all your calculation in the ```unshift``` function, as I do in my exemple.

Comment: Not really, because the validation does not know if the other value changes. See http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/vCFFQ/4/
Insert 2 into Int1, and 3 into Int2. Then change Int1 to 5, and Int2 stays valid even though it actually isn't :-)

Comment: Thx for the idea. Put a watcher in a directive save my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simpler solution would be with a watcher or even an expression inside the ng-show direcive of your error span.

Using an expression inside the ng-show directive would be like this:

```
<span ng-show="int1 > int2" style="color: red; display:none">
```

Otherwise you could watch for changes in the models int1 and int2 and compare their values:

```
$scope.$watch('int1+int2', function () {
    if($scope.int1 > $scope.int2) {
        $scope.error = true;    
    }else {
        $scope.error = false;
    }
}) 

<span ng-show="error" style="color: red; display:none">
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbcgU/6/)

Comment: excellent solution in case you are looking for some very complex validation rule and that rule is only required on a single page