# Trigger validation of a field when another field is changed

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I have a custom validation directive that is being called properly when one field is changed. However, whether this field is valid is also based on another field's value. This second field is a select list if that is of importance.

I was wondering if there was some way I could trigger validation manually when the second form is changed. Perhaps by using the `ng-change` event. What is the proper way to handle something like this?

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    directive('validage', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

                function validate(value) {
                    var valid = true;
                    if ((GetDateDifference(new Date(value), new Date()) < 16 || GetDateDifference(new Date(value), new Date()) > 129)
                    && scope.dep.DependantType == "Spouse") {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    ngModel.$setValidity('validage', valid);
                    return value;
                }

                //For DOM -> model validation
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                    var valid = true;
                    if ((GetDateDifference(new Date(value), new Date()) < 16 || GetDateDifference(new Date(value), new Date()) > 129)
                    && scope.dep.DependantType == "Spouse") {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    ngModel.$setValidity('validage', valid);
                    return value;
                });

                //For model -> DOM validation
                ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                    var valid = true;
                    if ((GetDateDifference(new Date(value), new Date()) < 16 || GetDateDifference(new Date(value), new Date()) > 129)
                    && scope.dep.DependantType == "Spouse") {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    ngModel.$setValidity('validage', valid);
                    return value;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

If you're new to AngularJS, I would definitely recommend reading these 2 articles: [part 1](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/08/designing-html-forms-angularjs-part-1) & [part 2](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/08/angularjs-html-form-design-part-2). They are an overview of AngularJS forms.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16886177/2057033) on StackOverflow.

Comment: with angular 1.3 this works in the directive: ngModel.$validate();

Comment: In anglular 1.2, you can manually trigger all the functions in $parsers with ngModel.$setViewValue(). So just set it to itself: ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue)

Answer (score 50):

After searching a lot for this I've found that we can trigger validation simply by calling `$validate()` on the desired field.
So for example if your form is named *my_form* (i.e. in the markup the form tag has a `name="my_form"` attribute) and the name of the field you want to validate is *date* (in the markup the input field has a `name="date"` attribute), then as you suggested you can use the `ng-change` event of the **second** field and call `$scope.my_form.date.$validate();` whenever the ng-change function is invoked.

Comment: Thank you! This also works in a directive by calling ngModel.$validate(); .. for example if you have attributes you observe you can revalidate the model :)

Comment: Which version of angular is this available? I'm using 1.2.18 and I am not seeing the $validate() function.

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.2. `$validate()` is available starting version 1.3.0. By the way, you can see some more info on the relations between ngmodel and the field's name here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/guide/forms, under _Binding to form and control state_.

Comment: Seems the problem with this is that the model's value becomes `undefined` if it is not valid.

Comment: To get around the model value being set to undefined when it is not valid, I added a hidden field that I attached the custom validator to.

Comment: You can do this right in html: `ng-change="my_form.date.$validate()"`

Comment: @gneri what if I want to validate the whole form instead of just a field? `my_form.$validate()` or `$scope.my_form.$validate()` does not do the trick :(

Comment: @gneri thanks, that just says if the form is valid or not, but doesn't trigger the validation. I finally used `$scope.my_form.$setValidity()` which seems to try to validate the whole form and ends showing the error messages, all I needed :D

Comment: Angular 8: `(ngModelChange)="controls.otherControl.updateValueAndValidity()"`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem: two form fields "interval" (for $scope.monitor.interval) and "timeout" (for $scope.monitor.timeout) with the condition that timeout must not exceed half of interval.

First, I added a custom validator to timeout that checks for this condition. Now I needed to trigger the timeout validator also when interval changes. I achieved this by watching the monitor.interval property of the model:

```
function EditMonitorCtrl($scope, $log, dialog, monitor) {
    $scope.monitor = monitor;

    ...

    // trigger validation of timeout field when interval changes
    $scope.$watch("monitor.interval", function() {
        if ($scope.editMonitorDlg.timeout.$viewValue) {          
            $scope.editMonitorDlg.timeout.$setViewValue($scope.editMonitorDlg.timeout.$viewValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Without "if" the timeout value got removed during intialisation of the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get `ng-blur="myForm.myField.$validate()"` working in AngularJS 1.5, possibly because the model for `myField` was empty.

However, `ng-blur="myForm.myField.$setTouched()"` did work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the directive to the second field and then altering the directive to add the error message to the field with the error. There might be a better way, but that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Reset the 2nd field on change of 1st field, will the trigger validation for 2nd field.

example on change event of 1st field.

```
const parentControls:any = control.parent.controls;

if(parentControls.secondField.value !==''){
   parentControls.secondField.setValue(parentControls.secondField.value);
}
```